# How to configure Sitecore CMS to show actual published content when switch to web database in content editor?

Tags: publishing

`Sitecore Web Database` content tree does not show the published home node in `Sitecore CMS` but it shows the default home node.

In Sitecore CMS, I could not see the published Home node with subitems(but on the CD website I am able to see published web content) instead I could see only the default home node with subitems.
Alter publishing, I could see Sitecore item getting published to Web DB but it does not update item count in the popup.

Please let me know what configuration files I should check to see web/published content when we switch to the web content tree in Sitecore CMS.

Master Content Tree :
[image]

Web Content Tree: [image: Sitecore Web Database Content Tree does not show the published home node in Sitecore CMS but it shows the default home node.]
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you see in master and web?

Comment: @MichaelWest Thank you your response. I have attached the screenshot for both master and web content tree.

Comment: Can you try to clear the cache? `https://yourlocaldomain/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx`

Comment: After clearing cache also the issue still persist.

Comment: Can your screenshots include which database is selected at the bottom right?

Comment: I have added new publishing target web2 that is same as web and published the item to same web db. Now I see all items in web content tree. Thank you

Comment: @KumariDimple What was the issue? Was it that the parent item was not published in the first place and you were trying to publish the child item?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that all you need to do is rebuild the `Sitecore web index`.

To confirm first of all the `web dB` that your `cm` instance is pointing to has published content. Please go to `/sitecore/admin/dbbrower.aspx` and browse the `web` database. This relies on database content rather than `solr` index.

If content appears there as expected, the go to `control panel -> rebuild solr index -> web index`.